# Is this a bug of IE8? table.rows is empty of dynamic generated table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, internet-explorer-8

Test page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>testcase</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="Foo()">Eat me</button>
    <button id="bar"><-- Hit it</button>
    <table id="testTable" onchange="Bar()"></table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Foo(){
            var table = document.getElementById("testTable");
            for(var i=0; i < 7; i++){
                var row = document.createElement("tr");
                for(var j=0; j < 7; j++){
                    var cell = document.createElement("td");
                    cell.innerHTML = i + "-" + j;
                    row.appendChild(cell);
                }
                table.appendChild(row);
            }
            Bar();
        }
        function Bar(){
            var bar = document.getElementById("bar");
            var table = document.getElementById("testTable");
            if(bar.textContent){
                bar.textContent = "table.rows.length = " + table.rows.length;
            }else{
                bar.innerText = "table.rows.length = " + table.rows.length;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

On Firefox 19, Chrome 26 or IE9+, the number after `table.rows.length =` is correct, however IE8 is always `0`, the `table.rows` itself seems empty too (I don't know how to prove that, the debug tool of IE won't display the content of Javascript object which Chrome and Firefox would). Seems IE8 have problem counting the rows of dynamically generated table :/

Comment: `<table>`s don't have `change` events btw :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do in this way also-

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>testcase</title>
</head>
<body>
    <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('testTable')" />    <button type="button" onclick="Bar()" id="bar">table.rows.length = 0</button>
    <table id="testTable">
</table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addRow(tableID) {
 alert(tableID);
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  for(var i=0; i < 7; i++){

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);


            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var element1 = document.createElement("input");
            element1.type = "checkbox";
            element1.name="chkbox[]";
            cell1.appendChild(element1);

            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;

            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var element2 = document.createElement("input");
            element2.type = "text";
            element2.name = "txtbox[]";
            cell3.appendChild(element2);
}

        }
        function Bar(){
alert(document.getElementById("testTable").rows.length);

            var bar = document.getElementById("bar");
            var table = document.getElementById("testTable");
            if(bar.textContent){alert("sdsds");
                bar.textContent = "table.rows.length = " + table.rows.length;
            }else{
                bar.innerText = "table.rows.length = " + table.rows.length;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is that an answer on why the OPs script does not work? Or is it a comment that `table.insertRow()`/`row.insertCell()` works neither in IE8?

Comment: @Bergi Its an another work around for your problem.I guess table.insertRow()/row.insertCell() this will also work in IE8.